# CNN training taking too long (hours)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu, conv-neural-network

I'm taking the udemy Deep Learning course, and when building my first image classification CNN with data augmentation I chose to try using my GPU (Nvidia GTX 1060) to speed up the process a little. As far as I know, It's meant to run in minutes on CPU only. But it's been 4-5 hours and I'm only at epoch 12/25. I've searched a lot and I can't find the explanation.
Also, my GPU-use is at 10% top, and CPU 20-26%.

My dataset is 8000 images for training and 2000 for testing.
I've installed keras-gpu from the Anaconda Navigator (that comes with tensorflow/tensorflow-gpu 2.1).

When I run the `nvidia-smi` command, I can see the python process in the last row but "N/A" at the Memory usage memory. Does this mean my CNN is not using GPU?

If that's the case, I don't understand why I did get my CPU and GPU devices when I ran this code:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

Here's the code and nvidia-smi info if you wanna inspect it:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense

classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size = 3, padding = 'same', input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = 2))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale= 1./255, shear_range = 0.2, zoom_range = 0.2, horizontal_flip = True)                     

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set', target_size = (64, 64), batch_size = 32, class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set', target_size = (64, 64), batch_size = 32, class_mode = 'binary')              

classifier.fit(training_set, steps_per_epoch = 8000, epochs = 25, validation_data = test_set, validation_steps = 2000, verbose = 2)
```

nvidia-smi:

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI>nvidia-smi
Mon Jun 01 01:15:59 2020
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 446.14       Driver Version: 446.14       CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 106... WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   64C    P2    24W /  N/A |   2510MiB /  3072MiB |     10%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU                  PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|                                                                  Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                  248    C+G   ...cw5n1h2txyewy\LockApp.exe    N/A      |
|    0                 2576    C+G   ...X2_APP\DolbyDAX2Toast.exe    N/A      |
|    0                 6152    C+G   ...es.TextInput.InputApp.exe    N/A      |
|    0                 9592    C+G   ...ekyb3d8bbwe\YourPhone.exe    N/A      |
|    0                16232      C   ...nvs\tensorflow\python.exe    N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try to follow the tips from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34759. I guess the problem is due to your **CUDA version**

Comment: Remove the steps_per_epoch parameter in your fit_generator call, it is not needed and you set it to 32 times the actual value, which would make training 32 times slower

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy should I remove it or just divide it by 32? I'm trying the 2nd option now, though

Comment: I solved it adding the `workers` and `max_queue_size` to the fitting and now it runs smoothly.